How to use React SignalR context dependencies prop
I have a component that should connect to SignalR using SignalRContext only once, when redux store updates a "userId" value. I'm trying to achieve that by it's dependencies. Which i understand works the same as useEffect dependency list i.e. only calculate when the values change using Object.is()
For some reason, it connects on every render of the component.
simplified code:
const currentSession = useSelector(sessionSelectors.session);
console.log(currentSession.userId);
return <SignalRContext.Provider
      url={`${config.apiAddr}/events?userId=${currentSession.userId}`}
      withCredentials={true}
      dependencies={[currentSession.userId]}> 
<ComponentUsingContext/>
</SignalRContext.Provider>

outputs to console:
499a88e3-9e2e-4346-93a2-6f9513cc3eef
499a88e3-9e2e-4346-93a2-6f9513cc3eef
[2024-12-20T19:27:00.066Z] Information: WebSocket connected to ws://localhost:3001/events?userId=499a88e3-9e2e-4346-93a2-6f9513cc3eef&id=ZnXcSS9yDg2WW-EB9wNuHQ.
[2024-12-20T19:27:00.079Z] Information: WebSocket connected to ws://localhost:3001/events?userId=499a88e3-9e2e-4346-93a2-6f9513cc3eef&id=Wn4qgop6Ua0CJuWjugl5kQ.

That tells me the SignalRContext "did it's thing" again on 2nd render even though the dependencies did not change.
How should this be done correctly?
